# Linking FlexBox to Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, flexbox

Im starting to learn about flexbox / Bootstrap with visual studio  code but I wonder how can I link flexbox to visual code , is it an extension ? when I searched for it it showed a flexbox cheatsheet only . Thanks !:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property `flex` is part of standard CSS, not a framework like Bootstrap.

The term 'Flexbox' simply refers to CSS 'Flexible Box Layout'. Hence there is nothing for you to link to in Visual Studio Code.

For more details about `flex` refer to Mozilla's CSS reference >>> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex